# react-native-chime-sdk setup devices before a meeting

Tags: react-native, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I'm using `amazon-chime-react-native` in my App. How I can get devices setup before the meeting start?
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-chime-react-native-demo

Only after **startMeeting** I can get the device list, but on a setup screen the meeting starts and I can hear second participant
`NativeFunction.startMeeting(meeting,attendee);`
So, this `NativeFunction.startMeeting` should be on Meeting screen.
I think I should start the session and after the meetingSession. How to do that?

Bridge.ts

```
import { NativeModules, NativeEventEmitter } from 'react-native';

/**
 * These are the function that will be called from native side
 * i.e. Native -> React Native
 *
 * NativeEventEmitter.onMeetingStart(meetingName)
 * NativeEventEmitter.onMeetingEnd()
 * NativeEventEmitter.onAttendeesJoin(attendeeInfo)
 * NativeEventEmitter.onAttendeesLeave(attendeeInfo)
 * NativeEventEmitter.onAddVideoTile(tileState)
 * NativeEventEmitter.onRemoveVideoTile(tileState)
 * NativeEventEmitter.onError(errorMessage)
 */
const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(
  NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge
);

export const MobileSDKEvent = {
  OnMeetingStart: 'OnMeetingStart',
  OnMeetingEnd: 'OnMeetingEnd',
  OnAddVideoTile: 'OnAddVideoTile',
  OnRemoveVideoTile: 'OnRemoveVideoTile',
  OnAttendeesJoin: 'OnAttendeesJoin',
  OnAttendeesLeave: 'OnAttendeesLeave',
  OnAttendeesMute: 'OnAttendeesMute',
  OnAttendeesUnmute: 'OnAttendeesUnmute',
  OnAudioDeviceChanged: 'OnAudioDeviceChanged',
  OnDataMessageReceive: 'OnDataMessageReceive',
  OnError: 'OnError',
};

export const MeetingError = {
  OnMaximumConcurrentVideoReached: 'OnMaximumConcurrentVideoReached',
};

export function getSDKEventEmitter() {
  return eventEmitter;
}

/**
 * These are functions available for React native to call on native
 * i.e. React Native -> Native
 *
 * NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.startMeeting(meetingId, userName)
 * NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.stopMeeting()
 * NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.setMute(isMute) -> boolean
 * NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.setCameraOn(isOn) -> boolean
 * NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.bindVideoView(reactTagId, tileId)
 * NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.unbindVideoView(reactTagId, tileId)
 * NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.setAudioDevice -> boolean
 * NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.getAudieDevicesList -> List<MediaDevice>
 */
export const NativeFunction = {
  startMeeting: NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.startMeeting,
  stopMeeting: NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.stopMeeting,
  setMute: NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.setMute,
  setAudioDevice: NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.setAudioDevice,
  getAudioDevicesList: NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.getAudieDevicesList,
  setCameraOn: NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.setCameraOn,
  bindVideoView: NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.bindVideoView,
  unbindVideoView: NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.unbindVideoView,
  switchCamera: NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.switchCamera,
  sendDataMessage: NativeModules.NativeMobileSDKBridge.sendDataMessage,
};
```

For Android:
NativeMobileSDKBridge.kt

```
    fun getAudieDevicesList(): WritableMap{
        val listAudioDevices = meetingSession?.audioVideo?.listAudioDevices()
        val map: WritableMap = WritableNativeMap()
        val list: WritableArray = WritableNativeArray()

        listAudioDevices?.forEach {
            val device: WritableMap = WritableNativeMap()
            device.putString("id",it.id)
            device.putString("label",it.label)
            device.putString("type",it.type.name)
            list.pushMap(device)
        }
        map.putArray("devices", list);

        return map;
    }
```

For iOS: NativeMobileSDKBridge.m

```
RCT_EXPORT_BLOCKING_SYNCHRONOUS_METHOD(getAudieDevicesList)
{
  NSArray *deviceList = [meetingSession.audioVideo listAudioDevices];
  NSArray *transformedList = [NSArray array];

  for (MediaDevice * device in deviceList) {
    transformedList = [transformedList arrayByAddingObject:@{
      @"label": device.label,
      @"type": [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", device.type],
    }];
  }

  return @{@"devices":transformedList};;
}
```

Here is my Setup view for configuration devices before the meeting:

```
const DeviceSetup: FC<Props> = ({ route }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const [microphones, setMicrophones] = useState([]);
  const [selectedMicrophone, setSelectedMicrophone] = useState();
  const [speakers, setSpeakers] = useState([]);
  const [selectedSpeaker, setSelectedSpeaker] = useState();

  const handleJoinToCall = useCallback(
    () =>
      navigation.dispatch(
        CommonActions.reset({
          index: 1,
          routes: [
            {
              name: PATHS.CALL,
              params: { ...route.params },
            },
          ],
        })
      ),
    []
  );
  const refreshDevices = useCallback(async () => {
    const deviceList = await NativeFunction.getAudioDevicesList();

    const microphonesList = deviceList?.devices.filter(
      (x: AudioDevice) => x.type === 'AUDIO_HANDSET' || x.type === '3'
    );
    const speakersList = deviceList?.devices.filter(
      (x: AudioDevice) => x.type === 'AUDIO_BUILTIN_SPEAKER' || x.type === '2'
    );
    setMicrophones(microphonesList);
    setSelectedMicrophone(microphonesList[0]);
    setSpeakers(speakersList);
    setSelectedSpeaker(speakersList[0]);
  }, []);

  const onDeviceChange = useCallback((device: any) => {
    if (device.type === 'AUDIO_BUILTIN_SPEAKER' || device.type === '2') {
      setSelectedSpeaker(device);
    } else if (device.type === 'AUDIO_HANDSET' || device.type === '3') {
      setSelectedMicrophone(device);
    }
  }, []);

  const requestPermissions = useCallback(async () => {
    const permissionIosCamera = await check(PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA);
    const permissionIosMicrophone = await check(PERMISSIONS.IOS.MICROPHONE);
    const permissionAndroidCamera = await check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA);
    const permissionAndroidMicrophone = await check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.RECORD_AUDIO);

    if (
      (permissionIosCamera === RESULTS.GRANTED &&
        permissionIosMicrophone === RESULTS.GRANTED) ||
      (permissionAndroidCamera === RESULTS.GRANTED &&
        permissionAndroidMicrophone === RESULTS.GRANTED)
    ) {
      refreshDevices();
      return;
    }

    if (
      (permissionIosCamera === RESULTS.DENIED &&
        permissionIosMicrophone === RESULTS.DENIED) ||
      (permissionAndroidCamera === RESULTS.DENIED &&
        permissionAndroidMicrophone === RESULTS.DENIED)
    ) {
      const result = await requestMultiple([
        PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA,
        PERMISSIONS.IOS.MICROPHONE,
        PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA,
        PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.RECORD_AUDIO,
      ]);

      if (
        (result[PERMISSIONS.IOS.CAMERA] === RESULTS.GRANTED &&
          result[PERMISSIONS.IOS.MICROPHONE] === RESULTS.GRANTED) ||
        (result[PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.CAMERA] === RESULTS.GRANTED &&
          result[PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.RECORD_AUDIO] === RESULTS.GRANTED)
      ) {
        refreshDevices();
      }
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    requestPermissions();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <>
          <Picker
            onChange={onDeviceChange}
            value={selectedMicrophone}
          >
            {microphones?.map((item: any) => (
              <Picker.Item key={item.type} label={item.label} value={item} />
            ))}
          </Picker>

          <Picker
            onChange={onDeviceChange}
            value={selectedSpeaker}
          >
            {speakers?.map((item: any) => (
              <Picker.Item key={item.type} label={item.label} value={item} />
            ))}
          </Picker>
        </>
      </View>

      <View>
        <Button
          onPress={handleJoinToCall}
          size='wide'
          title='NEXT'
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default DeviceSetup;
```